# Font size increase and contrast/Brightness,sound control of website using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Hi my client have a new requirement, he need to add Font size increase and contrast/Brightness,sound control  in his website.

[image]

So on clicking this any of the image a slider is appear and from this he can do the corresponding action .

[image]

How can i do this using jquery ?.At first , when clicking the anyone of the control images i need to appear a "+" ," - " slider like the second image.Please help .

Comment: Please post relevant code. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Unless there is code to debug, no one can help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. At first , when clicking the anyone of the control  images i need to appear a "+", " - " slider like the second image. Could you please explain how to do this ?

Comment: first step would be to learn jQuery.  Second step would be to actually try writing some code.  Third step, post said code on stackoverflow and ask for help.  Or you can skip all those and just hire a developer.

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a code writing service. The StackOverflow community will be more than happy to help you with issues with code you have written. I also highly doubt you will be able to adjust a monitors brightness from a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the small demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/692/

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a>Font</a>

            <div id="font" class="checked" data-min="8" data-max="100" data-step="1"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a>Brightness</a>

            <div id="brightness" class="checked" data-min="0" data-max="2" data-step="0.1"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a>Contrast</a>

            <div id="contrast" class="checked" data-min="8" data-max="100" data-step="1"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="demo">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lore</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    white-space:nowrap
}
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    position:relative
}
ul li .checked {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    display:none;
    left:0;
}
ul li a {
    display:block;
}
.demo {
    margin-top:100px;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #bfbfbf
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").on("click", "a", function () {
        $(this).next(".checked").toggle();
    });
    $(".checked").each(function () {
        $(this).slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            min: 0,
            step: parseFloat($(this).attr("data-step")),
            max: parseInt($(this).attr("data-max")),
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var value = ui.value;
                var type = $(this).attr("id");
                console.log(type)
                switch (type) {
                    case "font":
                        {
                            $(".demo").css("font-size", value + "px");
                            break;
                        }
                    case "brightness":
                        {
                            console.log(value);
                            $(".demo").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0," + value + ")");
                            break;
                        }
                    case "contrast":
                        {
                            //Your code
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

        });
    })
});
```

Resource Links: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide

Should be good for you to start. Just click on the font/brightness/contrast, slider will appear and then you can set the values.

Comment: Really thanks for your help.It should be very helpful to me .Many many thanks for creating a jsfiddle example. :) .This is very helpful for to start .

Answer (score 0):

I think this site may help you on this : http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-volumn-slider/

Comment: Thank you @jon P for your suggestion. I think this link will be helpful to ron r . The examples and demo is quite clear in the site, so I do not think it is not necessary to push the again here.
 From next time I will keep in mind that direct links will be not provided.

Comment: Thanks Nivs for giving this link.This link is very helpful for knowing the complete working .